# Calculate percentage difference from 2 columns in a matrix where we also have blanks in the column - power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix with values from multiple years, however some of the fields in the columns are blank.  I need to replace the blanks with nil then add column for % difference between the 2 years
(I am not able to add zeros to the data as the name will not appear if there was no delivery)

eg valuesyr1 valuesyr2 difference
1000      5000     4000
1000     1000
500                 500

I have tried and failed with a few dax formulas

Answer (score 0):

Use this **calculated column**

```
Difference = 
IF(
    ISBLANK('Table'[valuesyr1]),
    'Table'[valuesyr2],
    IF(
        ISBLANK('Table'[valuesyr2]),
        'Table'[valuesyr1],
        'Table'[valuesyr2] - 'Table'[valuesyr1]
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, it was the percentage difference I was trying to calculate

Comment: Not in your sample data plus it's stupid simple to amend the formula accordingly.